# Conformal mapping of periodic bladed boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, boundary-value-problem, conformal-geometry

I am new to conformal mapping and I am trying to find the mapping of the vertical boundary with tilted cuts to a horizontal boundary with perpendicular cuts (See the image). 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

[This image shows how the mapping should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVeoo.jpg)

I tried $w=z^\theta$, it works for the blade at z=0 but does not do what I want for other blades. See this figure.

[See the figure of map $w=z^\theta$ for periodic baldes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBRBw.jpg)

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! Can you also tell us what you already tried? If you show us that you already made an effort to solve the question, the community will be more willing to give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ernie060, I added what I have done so far.

Comment: $\arcsin(\sin(z)/\cosh(1))$ maps the polyline $[-\pi/2 + i, -\pi/2, \pi/2, \pi/2 + i]$ to the segment $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$; if you keep applying the symmetry principle to this function, you get a function that maps the upper half-plane minus the segments $[\pi/2 + \pi k, \pi/2 + \pi k + i$] to the upper half-plane. $\arcsin$ comes from the Schwarz–Christoffel mapping for a polygon with two $\pi/2$ angles. For slanted segments, the Schwarz–Christoffel mapping is no longer an elementary function.